# using for loop with in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

For a given array v=[1,2,3] I am trying to print the sum of the product of each element with s for a range of s

```
import numpy as np
v=[1,2,3]
for s in range(0,5):
    for i in range (0,3):
         tot= np.multiply(v[i],s)
         b.append(tot)
print (b)
```

my output is

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9, 4, 8, 12]
```

I am trying to get the out put as

```
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9], [4, 8, 12]]
```

I am not quite sure how the second for loop is working inside the first for loop. If someone can explain that, it would be wonderful.

Comment: Why the `np.multiply()` call? What's wrong with `v[i] * s`?

Comment: Just create a new list in the outermost `for` loop, append to that, and then append that list to `b` when the inner loop is done?

Comment: @MartijnPieters when I did v*2 instead of multiplying it just repeats the list twice

Comment: Yes, multiplying the original list would certainly do that. I'm asking why you didn't multiply the values *in* the list.

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a new list for each iteration of the outer `for` loop:

```
v=[1,2,3]
b = []
for s in range(0,5):
    result = []
    for i in range (0,3):
         tot= np.multiply(v[i],s)
         result.append(tot)
    b.append(result)
print (b)
```

You could just use `*` to multiply values, and you can iterate directly over `v` (no need to use a range)`:

```
v = [1, 2, 3]
b = []
for s in range(5):
    result = []
    for i in v:
        result.append(i * s)
    b.append(result)
```

You can replace both loops with list comprehensions:

```
b = [[i * s for i in v] for s in range(5)]
```

Comment: I tried to use the first approach with a list created outside the outer for loop ie just after b. Can you please explain why that didn't work.Thanks

Comment: @p.kumar: because then you'd have just *one* list, not a new list for every iteration of the outer `s in range(5)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
v=np.array([1,2,3])
b=[]
for s in range(0,5):
    b.append(list(v*s))
print (b)
```

Should do what you want. Don't forget numpy's extremely powerful [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) capability.

Answer (score 0):

```
v=[1,2,3]
b=[]
for s in range(0,5):
    b.append([])
    for i in range (0,3):
        tot= np.multiply(v[i],s)
         b[s].append(tot)    
print(b)
```